# VBA - Convert US date to EU date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a Excel/Windows configured with EU dates.

I'm trying to convert an US date to an EU date with VBA.

Input : `12-Dec-2020`

Expected output : `12/12/2020`

I already tried to use `sheet.Cells(row, col).Value = DateValue(currentCellValue)` where `currentCellValue = 12-Dec-2020`.

However, I'm facing below issue

> Type mismatch

Can you please explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance,

Regards

Comment: If you pick December 12, you won't know if you get it right.  Try December 22 in order to differentiate between the month and the day #

Comment: Is the value stored as text, or as a `DateTime` object?

Comment: Same issue with `16-Dec-2020`.

Comment: I guess it is a text object as it is align on the left of the cell.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "EU dates"? EU is big. What is the actual language, other than the order of day and month? (I don't need the actual language, just whether it's English or not, like it would be for e.g. UK locale which is not EU anymore though).

Comment: System is setup as "French (Luxembourg)".

Comment: Then it's not going to be able to recognize "Dec", is it?

Comment: Yes I think it is the reason why system is crashing.

Comment: However I dont understand how this answer can help me ...

Comment: It shows you how to parse your `12-Dec-2020` date on your French Excel. You don't even have to [look up a language identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f) because the `LANG_EN_US` will work just fine.

Comment: @GSerg thank you very much ! It seems to be ok.